# Agregar identificador incrementable a la etiqueta "name" de un input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy tratando de empujar con ayuda de un botn y javascript un contador incrementable al tag name de una etiqueta input de html cada que se le de click.

Alguien sabe de que manera podría lograrlo.

De antemano gracias.

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu pregunta... danos mas datos, ejemplos, porciones de codigo para poder ayudarte.   podría decirte que con un contador y una concatenacion se hacer, pero no te estaria ayudando en nada

Comment: Cesar, comparte el código que has intentado hasta ahora para lograr lo que quieres

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien, pero es simple el problema: Solo debes darle un evento al botón, declarar una variable global, en la función que llama el evento onclick del botón debes obtener el input y cambiar el atributo name por la variable global y aumentarle uno